# How to do operator overloading between two different classes in python

Tags: python, class, operator-overloading

Consider the main class

```
class point2D:
    def __init__(x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return vector2D(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)
```

and the subclass:

```
class vector2D(point2D):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return vector2D(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

now I want the `+` operator also to be able to add a `vector2D` and a `point2D` object and return a `point2D` object. And `-` operator between any of the classes to return `vector2D` anyway. I would appreciate if you could help me know if/how can I do that in Python `3.*`.

Comment: Why does `vector2D` subclass `point2D`? A vector is not a point.

Comment: well, mathematically speaking true, but computationally: it can inherit all the methods without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You clearly know how to overload operators. Use type checking to return objects of the desired type or [NotImplemented](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/constants.html#NotImplemented) in each case.

Comment: Would you be so kind to show me how it should be done? are you saying that I can put some if statements inside those methods and then return different things based on the input? probably using `isinstance`?

Comment: Exactly so. Please try that and update the question if you have more difficulties.